# Erro 405 Método não permitido asp.net web-api

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Ao tentar fazer a exclusão do registro, recebo esta mensagem, todas as outras operações está funcionando.

O código:

```html
        //http://www.sistemaguardiao.com.br/webapi/api/AspNetWebApi/deletar/jogo/4512/5
        //http://localhost:7630/api/AspNetWebApi/deletar/jogo/4512/5
        //precisa usar o postman com opção delete formato json
        [HttpDelete]
        [Route("deletar/jogo/{nJogo}/{idusuario}")]
        public HttpResponseMessage Deletar(int nJogo, int idusuario)
        {
            try
            {
                var tTabela = new JogoDetalheAplicacao();
                var resultado = tTabela.Excluir(nJogo, idusuario);
                return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, resultado);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

                return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, ex.Message);
            }
        }
```

Na aplicação:

```html
        public bool Excluir(int nJogo,  int idusuario)
        {
            var retorno = 0;
            var strQuery = string.Format("DELETE FROM TB_JOGO_DETALHE_TEMP WHERE NUMERO_JOGO = {0} AND IDUSUARIO = {1}; SELECT NUMERO_JOGO FROM TB_JOGO_DETALHE_TEMP WHERE NUMERO_JOGO = {0} AND IDUSUARIO = {1}", nJogo, idusuario);
            using (contexto = new Contexto())
            {
                var reader = contexto.ExecutaComandoComRetorno(strQuery);
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    retorno = Convert.ToInt32(reader["NUMERO_JOGO"]);
                }
                reader.Close();
            }

            if (retorno == 0)
                return true;
            return false;
        }
```

http://www.sistemaguardiao.com.br/webapi/api/AspNetWebApi/deletar/jogo/4512/5

http://www.sistemaguardiao.com.br/webapi/api/AspNetWebApi/datahora/consulta

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Lendo o primeiro link você está tentando deletar usando o método GET. Mas precisa mostrar nó código como você está fazendo.

Comment: @leopiazzoli, estou usando o Delete, eu postei o código é o endereço que pode ser testado, agradeço